# "generated data and information" vs "data and information generated"

Tags: grammar, adjectives, participles

The data and information generated are best interpreted in face-to-face meetimg.

or

The generated data and information are best interpreted in face-to-face meetimg.

Which is correct? is there difference in meaning?

Answer (score 0):

Either word order is fine. See this similar question:

[Help with Participle constructions, such as "the discussed problems" vs. "the problems discussed"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/63487/help-with-participle-constructions-such-as-the-discussed-problems-vs-the-pr?rq=1)

As pointed out there - in the phrase "generated data and information", "generated" is a participial adjective - the past participle of "to generate" ("generated") is used as an adjective.

In the phrase "data and information generated", "generated" is shorthand for the clause "that have been generated".

Both phrases indicate that data and information have been generated in the past, and both are grammatical.

I would make a few other corrections to either of those entire sentences, though:

> "...**would be** best interpreted in **a** face-to-face meeting"

You should use the conditional mood because the meeting is hypothetical - it doesn't yet exist. And make sure to use an indefinite article - in general you cannot omit the article from a singular noun in English.